# Is it possible to add XML attributes to RDF/XML property elements?

Tags: java, xml, rdf, jena

I am working on an RDF document where I want to add attribute `b:type="OAId"` to a property element, as in the following.  Is this possible?  I'm using Jena.

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
         xmlns:b="http://example.com/pred">

<rdf:Description   
    rdf:about="http://example.com/pred/I995aa63fa85411e28578f7ccc38dcbee">
    <rdf:type>Company</rdf:type>
    <b:markedText>OKLAHOMA CORPORATION COMMISSION</b:markedText>
    <b:target b:type="OAId">5026393404</b:target>  <!-- extra attribute b:type -->
    <!-- ... -->
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Can you explain in natural language what you want to achieve?

Comment: Is there a way to add custom literal to property similar to typed literal which Jena API has.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an XML attribute where you want to add one, you won't have legal RDF/XML anymore.  If I paste your snippet into the [W3C's validator](https://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/), I get the error message:

> Error: {E201} The attributes on this property element, are not permitted with any content; expecting end element tag.[Line = 8, Column = 39]

Comment: Thanks Taylor. But Apache Jena provides Typed literals as shown below:   <rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:eg="http://example.org/" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://example.org/company">
    <eg:reference rdf:resource="http://example.org/party"/>
    <eg:target rdf:datatype="OAID">0456253</eg:target>
  </rdf:Description>                                                                                    where rdf:datatype="OAID" is a typed literal which is an attribute for <eg:target> predicate. Similar way can we create custom literal?

Comment: @hyma Sure, you can create literals with any datatype you want, but the xml attribute on the property will be rdf:datatype, not b:type, like in your example. It's the *value* of the rdf:datatype attribute that is the datatype of the literal.

Comment: Thanks Joshua. This is helpful